# how can phone apk detect the intent is from my wear apk? not other apk or program?

Tags: security, wear-os

I have a wear apk and a phone apk with the same signature and package name.
how can i detect the intent is from my wear apk? not other apk or program?
And specifically，the scene is my phone app have a picture, and i want to send the picture to wear, but i can not detect who request the picture.

i have try many method to do this, but they are not security enough.
in android wear os, google will check the signature of the app, if the signatures are same, they can exchange message with each other. but i want to check it by my self, i can not believe google.

Comment: Why you don't put some field in your intent to diff wear's from phone's intents?

Comment: You can't send Intents across devices (I.e., from Wear to phone). Do you instead mean something like using the `DataApi`?

Comment: Why you don't put some field in your intent to diff wear's from phone's intents?
this is not security enough, because it can not prevent other apk send the same filed to you phone app

Answer (score 0):

You can define a permission with permission level of "signature".

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Comment: this can not work, because wear apk is in wear device and connect phone with bluetooth